# Performance improvement from VS 2005 to VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Please let me know the performance improvement factors from VS 2005 to VS 2012.
Ex: List to HashSet

I want to know the points in the above angle.

Comment: It is more or less exactly 3.1415 times faster ...

Answer (score 1):

It may be more relevant to consider the differences between .Net Framework 3 and .Net Framework 4.5...

For performance improvements in .Net 4.5;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882452.aspx

*In general*, the following describes the differences between the .Net Versions.

**For .Net 4.5:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx

**For .Net 4:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171868(v=vs.100).aspx

**For .Net 3.5 SP1:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc713697(v=vs.90).aspx

**For .Net 3.5:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb332048(v=vs.90).aspx

Regarding your specific example, where there may not be a direct performance improvement for converting between List and HahSet, there may be better ways of dealing with both Types in your code, for instance, Linq was introduced at .Net Framework 3.5, which isn't available as part of VS 2005.